DS389 password policy to force reset on login for expired passwords when using ssh
I'm using DS389 for LDAP and have setup password policies with password must change on for a RHEL8 server. The issue is if the password is expired and I login in via SSH with an LDAP account
I'm only warned that the password has expired and allowed on until I hit grace limit.
I would expect that when password expire I would be prompted to reset the password. Like it does with the admin reset which triggers the pwdReset to be true.
How do you get the system to prompt for password reset on a expired password?
the sssd logs show it under stands the password is expired
(2024-06-15  6:55:15): [be[default]] [simple_bind_done] (0x2000): [RID#8] Server returned control [1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1].
(2024-06-15  6:55:15): [be[default]] [simple_bind_done] (0x1000): [RID#8] Password Policy Response: expire [-1] grace [10] error [No error].
(2024-06-15  6:55:15): [be[default]] [simple_bind_done] (0x1000): [RID#8] Password expired. [10] grace logins remaining.
(2024-06-15  6:55:15): [be[default]] [simple_bind_done] (0x2000): [RID#8] Server returned control [2.16.840.1.113730.3.4.4].
(2024-06-15  6:55:15): [be[default]] [simple_bind_done] (0x1000): [RID#8] Password expired, user must set a new password.

sssd conf is
[sssd]
services = nss, pam, ssh, sudo
config_file_version = 2
domains = default


[domain/default]
debug_level = 10

id_provider = ldap
auth_provider = ldap
chpass_provider = ldap
access_provider = ldap
cache_credentials = True
pwd_expiration_warning = 7

min_id = 5000
max_id = 100000

ldap_schema = rfc2307bis
ldap_uri = ldaps://ldap.testing2.test.com:30636
ldap_chpass_dns_service_name = default
ldap_id_use_start_tls = False
ldap_tls_reqcert = demand
ldap_tls_cacert = /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt

ldap_default_bind_dn = cn=Directory Manager

ldap_default_authtok_type = password
ldap_default_authtok = 

ldap_search_base = dc=testing2,dc=test,dc=com,dc=au
ldap_user_search_base = ou=users,dc=testing2,dc=test,dc=com
ldap_group_search_base = ou=groups,dc=testing2,dc=test,dc=com

enumerate = True

# This is really important as it allows SSSD to respect nsAccountLock
ldap_account_expire_policy = rhds
ldap_chpass_update_last_change = true
ldap_access_order = expire

ldap_user_member_of = memberof
ldap_user_name = uid
ldap_user_gecos = gecos
ldap_user_uid_number = uidNumber
ldap_user_gid_number = gidNumber
ldap_user_home_directory = homeDirectory
ldap_user_shell = loginShell
ldap_user_uuid = nsUniqueId
ldap_group_uuid = nsUniqueId
ldap_user_modify_timestamp = modifyTimestamp
#ldap_ns_account_lock = nsAccountLock
ldap_user_ssh_public_key = nsSshPublicKey
ldap_user_fullname = cn

ldap_group_name = cn
ldap_group_gid_number = gidNumber
ldap_group_member = memberuid
ldap_group_modify_timestamp = modifyTimestamp

# This prevents an issue where the Directory is recursively walked on group
# and user look ups. It makes the client faster and more responsive in almost
# every scenario.
ignore_group_members = False

[nss]
debug_level = 10
filter_users = root, ldap, named, avahi, haldaemon, dbus, radiusd, news, nscd
homedir_substring = /home

[pam]
debug_level = 10
pam_pwd_expiration_warning = 3

[sudo]

[ssh]
debug_level = 10

and the password policy is setup like
nsslapd-pwpolicy-local: on
passwordstoragescheme: SHA512
passwordchange: on
passwordmustchange: on
passwordhistory: on
passwordinhistory: 3
passwordadmindn:
passwordadminskipinfoupdate: off
passwordtrackupdatetime: on
passwordwarning: 10
passwordisglobalpolicy: off
passwordexp: on
passwordmaxage: 30
passwordminage: 0
passwordgracelimit: 15
passwordsendexpiringtime: off
passwordlockout: on
passwordunlock: on
passwordlockoutduration: 300
passwordmaxfailure: 5
passwordresetfailurecount: 300
passwordchecksyntax: on
passwordminlength: 8
passwordmindigits: 1
passwordminalphas: 0
passwordminuppers: 1
passwordminlowers: 1
passwordminspecials: 1
passwordmin8bit: 0
passwordmaxrepeats: 0
passwordpalindrome: off
passwordmaxsequence: 0
passwordmaxseqsets: 0
passwordmaxclasschars: 0
passwordmincategories: 4
passwordmintokenlength: 3
passwordbadwords:
passworduserattributes: displayName uid cn givenName sn
passworddictcheck: off
passworddictpath:
nsslapd-allow-hashed-passwords: off
nsslapd-pwpolicy-inherit-global: off
passwordTPRMaxUse: -1
passwordTPRDelayExpireAt: -1
passwordTPRDelayValidFrom: -1

